# Lock TextBox from moving and resizing in a sheet and only edit the text Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, textbox

I create a TextBox in vba where Users enter a value then search it in the sheet as you can see here

[image]

My problem is I want to lock this TextBox from moving and the Users can just edit the text inside the box. I was trying Properties and checked "Locked" and unchecked "Locked Text" then protected the sheet

```
Sub protect_TextBox()

ActiveSheet.Protect UserInterFaceOnly:=True
'rest of my code...

End Sub
```

It locked my TextBox from moving and resizing and users can only edit the text inside

But it locked also many funtions like filtering, formating... basically i can just select the cell nothing more.

Any suggestions please how to freeze only the TextBox and keep the rest of cells unprotected ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: To do that, right click on the TextBox --> Format Control --> Properties --> and check the radio button for "Don't move or size with cells". Is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: thanks for your comment, i tried this before and it's not what i wanted. I want when you select the TextBox you can only edit the text inside. You can move the textbox or resize as you can see in the picture. I want the borders to be fixed, just lines not as you see there are the circles and rectangles on the borders

Comment: The "circles and rectangles" indicate that the shape has been *selected* by the users. Placing the cursor within the textbox (e.g., to allow the user to change the *text*) will automatically consider the shape *selected* and the "circles and rectangles" will appear. This is not preventable AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

The `worksheet.protect` method has many arguments that allow/disallow the user to do certain things.  Most of the arguments default to disallow if not specified in the `worksheet.protect` method.  See here for a full list of the arguments the method takes[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-protect-method-excel](http://link)

Maybe try something like this:

```
Sub protect_TextBox()

ActiveSheet.Protect UserInterFaceOnly:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True, _
AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
'rest of my code...

End Sub
```

You can see the other arguments on the link and include whatever you need.  Remember that the default of the arguments is false.  So if you do not include them there will be more restrictions on what the user can do to the cell.

Comment: You might want to mention specifically that the protection should *not allow* the user to "Edit Objects". This way, user can edit the text without being able to manipulate the textbox itself. This also gets rid of the "circles & rectangles" surrounding the textbox when it is normally *selected*.